# SpringLiquibase работа с ресурсами

Tags: java, spring

В моем проекте есть тестовый модуль, и модули-pojo с hibernate entity классами.

Тест содержит бин `SpringLiquibase`, задача которого перед запуском тестов накатить changelog.xml, находящийся вместе с entity классами.

Все в порядке, если changelog находится в каталоге тестового модуля. При попытке поднять модуль, указав путь относительно корня проекта, возникает исключение.

Структура:

```
|-project
 |-pojo-module
   |-src
     |-main
       |-resources
         |-db
           |-changelog.xml
 |-model-test
   |-src
     |-main
       |-java
         |-test
           |-config
             |-LiquibaseConfig.java
   |-resources
     |-liquibase.properties
```

Бин:

```
@Configuration
@Import(OracleDatabaseConfig.class)
public class LiquibaseConfig  {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LiquibaseConfig.class);

    @Value("${liquibase.changelog.path}")
    private String changelogPath;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    SpringLiquibase springLiquibase(){
        SpringLiquibase springLiquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        springLiquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        springLiquibase.setDropFirst(drop);
        springLiquibase.setChangeLog(changelogPath);
        springLiquibase.setChangeLogParameters(properties());
        return springLiquibase;
    }
```

Путь до changelog задан в конфигурации таким образом:

```
liquibase.changelog.path=\\cdm-hbm-mapping\\ekpit-model\\src\\main\\resources\\db\\changelog.xml
```

Исключение:

> ```
> Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [cdm-hbm-mapping/ekpit-model/src/main/resources/db/changelog.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
>     at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:112)
>     at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:17)
>     at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:229)
>     at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
>     at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
>     at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
>     at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
>     ... 59 more
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [cdm-hbm-mapping/ekpit-model/src/main/resources/db/changelog.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
>     at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195)
>     at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.getResourcesAsStream(SpringLiquibase.java:161)
>     at liquibase.util.StreamUtil.singleInputStream(StreamUtil.java:186)
>     at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:93)
>     ... 67 more
> ```

Пробовал так же получить экземпляр загрузчика классов, принадлежащих искомому модулю, но получил исключение.

```
try {
    springLiquibase.setChangeLog(AccessValue.class.getClassLoader().getResource(changelogPath).getFile());
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Исключение:

```
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [D:/Projects/cdm-ora/model-test/target/test-classes/db/changelog.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
                at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:112)
                at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:17)
                at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:229)
                at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
                at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
                at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
                at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
                ... 59 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [D:/Projects/cdm-ora/model-test/target/test-classes/db/changelog.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
                at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195)
                at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.getResourcesAsStream(SpringLiquibase.java:161)
                at liquibase.util.StreamUtil.singleInputStream(StreamUtil.java:186)
                at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:93)
                ... 67 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего помещать файл скриптов в resources в папку liquibase.
Конфигурация будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:/liquibase/liquibase-changelog.xml");
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema("auth");
        liquibase.setDropFirst(false);
        liquibase.setLiquibaseSchema("auth");

        return liquibase;
    }
```